# x86 pointers in commands

Tags: pointers, x86

I'm new to x86.

I know what this kind of thing with the pointers means.

```
*command* %eax, %ebx
```

But how are these different, and what do they mean?

```
*command* %eax, (%ebx)
*command* (%eax), %ebx
*command* (%eax, %ebx, 4), %ecx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is, "what does the parentheses around a register's name mean/do?"  At a high level, the parentheses say to perform a load from a memory address in and use that value in the instruction.  Ie, whereas

```
*command* %eax, %ebx
```

operates on the values in the `%eax` and `%ebx` registers directly,

```
*command* (%eax), (%ebx)
```

loads the values from memory pointed to by `%eax` and `%ebx` and operates on them.  There are actually a few more variants of the parentheses than you listed.  For a description of them (including the last instruction example that you asked about), check [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Address_operand_syntax).

Hope that helps.  Feel free to post back if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the following operations:

```
movl %eax, (%ebx)               [1]
movl (%eax), %ebx               [2]
movl (%eax, %ebx, 4), %ecx      [3]
```

1, The first one will copy the value of `eax` into an address stored in `ebx`, smiler to this in C:

```
*(int *)ebx = eax;    // copy eax into address
```

2, The second will copy the value stored in an address at `eax` into `ebx`:

```
ebx = *(int *)eax;    // copy what in address into ebx
```

3, This is an array operation, where `ebx` is the index and `4` is the size of an element of the array.

```
ecx = ((int *) p)[ebx];
```

calculated as:

```
ecx = *(int *)((char *)p + ebx * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

In AT&T asm syntax, parenthesis mean "dereference" -- roughly the same as the unary `*` operator in C.  So some rough equivalences:

```
movl  %eax, %ebx            eax = ebx
movl  %eax, (%ebx)          eax = *ebx
movl  (%eax), %ebx          *eax = ebx
```

That leqaves your last example:

```
movl  (%eax, %ebx, 4), %ecx
```

In this case, there are multiple values that are combined to form the address to dereference.  It's roughly equivalent to

```
*(eax + ebx*4) = ecx
```